# trying to find preferences.plist file

Tags: macos, network, plist

I am reading an old developer guide, that hasnt updated since 2007..

I want to access the file called `preferences.plist` located at `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist.`

It should look like this:

[image]
However, at that location there is no such file. I only found `com.apple.systempreferences.plist`, but this is not the right one. My guess is that it was moved over the years. Where could I find it? It contains data about network configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the file has not moved. It is still located at `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`.

Please make sure you are not in your User's Library folder (`~/Library/Preferences/`).

The best way to go to the correct folder in Finder is to use the menu item `Go > Go to Folder...`, or press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, and enter the folder you need to go to. In this case, `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`.

Comment: thank you. You were spot on! so the ~ sign means user. Is it possible to go to /Library/... without typing in the path?

Comment: Yes, if you make sure you have navigated to the root of your hard drive (`/`). This may be clicking on your hard drive on your desktop (such as `Macintosh HD`), or the same in your Finder sidebar, or by navigating to `Computer` and then the same.

Comment: thank you! Recently switched from windows to start programming and I am still finding my way around. This was really helpful.

Comment: The `~/` means current user's home directory in every UNIX-like operating system. By POSIX rules, the actual home directory location can be queried like this: `getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f6`.